# React Native project runs in Android Studio but not from terminal

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I am new to both react-native and JS. I am facing this issue where when I run my project on device using Android Studio 'run', it works. But when I try to run it using "react-native run-android" command, it doesn't run with following error:

> What went wrong:
>   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Could not create service of type AnnotationProcessorDetector using JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().

This error also shows when I try to build debug Apk.

Comment: it will run with sudo react-native run-android . But it is not the right form